# Exception/ Alert reporting

Tags: reporting

Is it possible to set up either reports or alerts in Salesforce to monitor activity on Opportunities? I am trying to create either reports or alerts on the following:

1. Opportunities whose Stage have not advanced in 30days
2. Opportunities whose Stage has regressed
3. Opportunities whose Close Date has beene extended
4. Opportunities whose Revenue Amount has changed

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create all type of reports and then subscribe to all the reports. Other option is to create all report and use all these reports on dashboard and just subscribe to dashboard. When you will be subscribed, it will send you notification on daily,weekly or monthly basis.